# MS Access Subquery that returns Multiple Fields

Tags: sql, subquery, ms-access-2007

So im back again with more MS Access problems. I have a INSERT INTO query with a subquery that checks to see if the data already exists.

```
SELECT name, course
FROM foo    
WHERE (name, course) NOT IN (SELECT name, course FROM bar);
```

to expound a little on what i am trying to accomplish since the above doesn't work.

I am trying to select composite keys that do not exist already in the table bar. For example the following could be stored in the table bar:

```
"John Doe" , "Calc 101" 
"John Doe" , "English"
"Jane Doe" , "Calc 101"
```

And the following could be in the table foo:

```
"John Doe", "Calc 101"
"John Doe", "Science"
```

The query should return the following:

```
"John Doe", "Science"
```

Everywhere i have looked says the above will work and im sure it does in theory. The problem i run into is with MS Access... When i attempt to run this query it pops up stating that the subquery will return multiple fields. Indeed it should as that is what i want it do do is return 2 fields that i can compare the other 2 fields. The above 2 fields are a composite key in my "bar" database.

For more background I am using MS Excel 2007 and MS Access 2007. The Excel is being used to input data and running the query through VB script. I am trying to make a subquery that checks for fields already in the final database because i ran into the error of MS Access opening up and spitting out a ERROR message about appending primary keys and closes with out executing the query. <-- That is to be expected due to the composite key.

Comment: You say "Everywhere i have looked says the above will work..." can you show your sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and look for `NULL` values:

```
SELECT bar.name, bar.course
FROM bar LEFT JOIN foo ON bar.name = foo.name AND bar.course = foo.course
WHERE foo.name IS NULL
```

I've updated the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e61b/1) to include the `INSERT` followed by a `SELECT` to show the final table. I've also added composite primary keys to both tables so you can see that you do not get any duplicate inserts.

Comment: Thank you Tony. I think is what i needed and the SQLFiddle you built helped me understand it a lot better. I will play with it a little more just to make sure but i believe it will work ^_^

Comment: so i have a follow on question after playing with the SQLfiddle for a bit. I noticed if i try to add a INSERT INTO clause above the query. (I did this assuming i could append the records returned to a table) the SQL Fiddle returned zero records. It may be that i dont understand the SQLFiddle but i currently am not at the office to test my finding in the access enviornment

Comment: @JohnathonHall - I've updated the SQL Fiddle to perform the `INSERT` as well.

Comment: Thanks I just didnt put the Select query after the insert. Just me not knowing how to use SQL Fiddle. Thanks again. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

your sub query is returning two columns.  make it return one.  If want a where clause that can be in two columns, use OR

```
SELECT name, course
FROM foo    
WHERE (name) NOT IN (SELECT name FROM bar) and (course) 
NOT IN (SELECT course FROM bar);
```

Edit:

Your problem stems from a normalization issue.  A suggested redesign would be to have a table for students and a table for courses and a table to join them.  Example:

```
**StudentTable**
studentId(int PK)
firtName(string)
lastName(string)

**ClassTable**
classId(int PK)
ClassName
ClassDesc

**classTable_studentTable**
studentClassID
studentID
classID
```

Each student can have many classes and each class can have many students.  It's a many to many relationship that is normalized by using the join table.

Now, if you wanted to do a query like your asking:

```
Select *.student, *.class
from
studentTable as student,
classTable as class
where
student.name<>'allen' and class.name<>'math'
```

Comment: So I guess im not following all of what you have said. I would like to understand vs just copy paste and be like yay it works. But with the Where clause is basicly 2 sub querys now. Does this return composite values?

Comment: Logically, both our sub queries are saying the same thing.  I just split up the where clause.  Instead of saying WHERE values in ('col1','col2') i'm saying where values in 'col1' and values in 'col2.  Just as a side note, though, the reason you are having difficulty is because your tables are not normalized.  You should not have redundant data in your tables (multiple Johnathan Hall's, for example.  I will edit my response to show you have to normalize them

Comment: @jason - The original table is normalised if the primary key is a composite of name and course. Your addition of surrogate keys does not help matters; in fact if your classTable_studentTable primary key is studentClassID then you can end up with multiple rows of a student taking the same class.

Comment: Thats why I added the studentClassID as the PK and did not use a composite key, as you can have the same student take the same course. Unless you introduce a Semester table to differentiate between when the same student took the same course.  Also, your example table is not normalized as you would have all kinds of update/delete anomalies if you had to change a students last name or course name

Comment: The OP does not mention anything about duplicate rows and in fact already has a composite key on this table. The question does not state  "...you can have the same student take the same course." And how would an update query such as UPDATE table SET name = 'Jane Smith' WHERE name = 'Jane Doe' cause anomalies if it's a primary key in the Student table?